# Is following Integral Solvable?

Tags: calculus

My friend's professor raised this question in a coaching and he and I tried everything we could think of. But later I thought that since $\sin (2x) $ can have values only between -1 & +1 and anything but +1 makes the equation complex ( keeping in mind that the integral is meant to be non-complex), there is no solution to the integral. Am I correct?

$\int \sqrt {\sin(2x)-1}$

Comment: It is integrable over the domain of the function. In particular, it is integrable on $[0, \pi/2]$.

Comment: Thanks! but isn't it integrable over $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ to $\pi$ also?

Comment: I could swear when I saw it yesterday, that itegrand was $\sqrt{\sin 2x}$. But obviously not, since there are no edits. Your original stand is correct, The integrand is purely imaginary ($0$ is both real and imaginary), so its integral is also imaginary. Therefore this integral has no real solution. The solutions offered in the answers are imaginary functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int \sqrt {\sin(2x)-1}dx$$
Substitute $u=2x$ and $du=2dx$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int \sqrt {\sin(u)-1}du$$
Substitute $s=\sin u -1$ and $ds = \cos u \,du$ and notice that $\cos u = \sqrt{1-\sin^2u} = \sqrt{1-(s+1)^2} = \sqrt{1-(s^2  + 2s + 1)} = \sqrt{1- s^2  - 2s - 1} = \sqrt{-s^2  - 2s} = \sqrt{-s(s+2)}$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\sqrt {s}}{\cos(u)}ds$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\sqrt {s}}{\sqrt{-s(s+2)}}ds$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int \sqrt{\frac{s}{-s(s+2)}}ds$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int \sqrt{\frac{1}{-(s+2)}}ds$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{-s-2}}ds$$
Substitute $p=-s-2$ and $dp=-ds$
$$= -\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dp}{\sqrt{p}}$$
Can you take it from here now? Just integrate and then back substitute

Comment: Nopes, this doesn't help, read above ansewer's comment

Comment: @prakharlondhe I''m positive this works, because I did out all the steps. You end up with$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{-s-1}}ds$ after another substitution if I remember correctly, and you only deal with real numbers. I decided to condense it and make it a hint though so you can get some practice with these. I can expand the answer if you would like. There is only one answer and it is non-complex. How you get there doesn't matter.

Comment: Its nice of you sir, but the $-$ sign under the root will yield complex result won't it? I mean i don't know if we can integrate the square root without paying attention to the complex part. The thing is I haven't learned complex integration yet.

Comment: @prakharlondhe No, you dont end up with a complex integral... It's entirely solvable using a trig substitution and then a power rule substitution... this is entirely constrained to the real numbers. The answer is $$\frac{(\sin x+\cos x)\sqrt{\sin(2 x)-1} }{\cos x-\sin x}+constant$$

Comment: @prakharlondhe This is the answer I got, just with slightly different work. See this link for proof of what I'm saying (also note that this answer is entirely real, so the integral is entirely real): https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%5Csqrt+%7B%5Csin%282x%29-1%7D

Comment: @prakharlondhe I have updated my answer with more steps, in order to help you out a bit here. As you can see, no complex integration is needed.

Comment: here's what i got :- 
after integration, $-\sqrt{p} = -\sqrt{-(s+2)} = -\sqrt{-sin(2x)-1}$ 
Now what?

Comment: @prakharlondhe Nothing. I should also note that wolfram alpha's answer is much longer than it has to be, for unknown reasons... perhaps to get the original equation into the answer? What you get is  $-\sqrt{p} + c = -\sqrt{-s-2} + c = -\sqrt{-\sin u - 1} + c = -\sqrt{-2\sin x \cos x- 1} + c = \sqrt{-\sin(2x)- 1} + c$ I would honestly just leave the answer like this... you have found your answer.

Comment: oh i understand now, this function is integrable over the domain in which sin(2x) is negative. i.e $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\pi$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ to $2\pi$... am i right?

Comment: @prakharlondhe a distinction needs to be made here: you can treat the function like you do all others you have likely worked with up until now, even if the real part is $0$ for any evaluated point. Both the original equation and the antiderivative give complex values when evaluated at a point, but just because a function does that doesn't necessarily mean you can't antidifferentiate it the same way you do any function that only returns real numbers with an imaginary part of 0.

Comment: @prakharlondhe I should also note that the solution $-\sqrt{-\sin(2x)- 1}$ varies from the one Wolfram Alpha gives when plotted, as WA's solution is only the same for values where the derivative of the imaginary part is greater than $0$.

Answer (score 1):

yes. its solvable
let $$\sin2x-1=t$$
then $$\cos2x= {\sqrt{t^2+2t}}$$
then after all simplification you'll get $$ \int \frac{2}{\sqrt{2-t}}.dt$$
now you can integrate it easily.

Comment: sorry bro the solution is wrong,$$\cos (2x)$$ will be equal to $$\sqrt{-t^2-2t}$$ which will again yield complex result.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For starters, write $\sqrt{\sin2x-1}=\sqrt{-(1-\sin2x)}=i\sqrt{1-\sin2x}~.~$ Then remember the fact that there are well-known [trigonometric formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae) for $1\pm\cos2t$. So, how do we go from $\sin2x$ to $\cos2t$ ? Well, by using $\sin u=\cos\bigg(\dfrac\pi2-u\bigg)$. Can you take it from here ? ;-$)$